# SystemC: Multiple module implementations in single cpp file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, systemc

Edit: Solution found by moving the `SC_HAS_PROCESS(Module);` statements from the .cpp file into the class definition in the header file.

I am writing  a module in SystemC which has small sub-modules. I would like to keep all of the declarations in a single header file, and the implementation on a single `.cpp` file. I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with this approach, but I am getting an error related to the use of the `SC_HAS_PROCESS` macro redefining `SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE`.

```cpp
In file included from /.../systemc/2.3.1/include/systemc:72:0,
                 from src/Decoder.cpp:39:
/.../systemc/2.3.1/include/sysc/kernel/sc_module.h:403:30: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct Fifo_shift SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE’
     typedef user_module_name SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE
                              ^
src/Decoder.cpp:146:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘SC_HAS_PROCESS’
 SC_HAS_PROCESS(Fifo_shift);
 ^
/.../systemc/2.3.1/include/sysc/kernel/sc_module.h:403:30: error: ‘SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct Decoder SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE’
     typedef user_module_name SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE
                              ^
src/Decoder.cpp:50:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘SC_HAS_PROCESS’
 SC_HAS_PROCESS(Decoder);
```

The error seems to be from my second use of `SC_HAS_PROCESS`. The general format of my code is as follows (with portions removed for brevity).

In '**Decoder.h**':

```cpp
SC_MODULE(Fifo_shift)
{
public:
  /* Port declarations */

  /* Variable declarations */

  Fifo_shift(sc_module_name nm, int chunk_size_in);
  ~Fifo_shift();

  /* Member functions */
private:
  /* Private variables */
};

/* Other modules */

SC_MODULE(Decoder)
{
public:
  /* Port declarations */

  /* Variable declarations */

  Decoder(sc_module_name nm, int num_mac_in); // constructor
  ~Decoder(); // destructor

  /* Member functions */
private:
  /* Private variables */
};
```

In '**Decoder.cpp**':

```cpp
/* First Use of SC_HAS_PROCESS */
SC_HAS_PROCESS(Decoder);
Decoder::Decoder(sc_module_name nm, int num_mac_in) :
   /* Member variable init */ 
{
  /* Do some initializing of dynamic variables */

  /* Connect sub-modules */

  /* Specify thread process */
  SC_THREAD(do_Decoder);
    sensitive << CLK.pos();
}

// Destructor
Decoder::~Decoder()
{ /* Delete dynamic variables */ }

void Decoder::do_Decoder()
{ /* Process implementation */ }




/* Second use of SC_HAS_PROCESS */
SC_HAS_PROCESS(Fifo_shift);
Fifo_shift::Fifo_shift(sc_module_name nm, int chunk_size_in) :
  /* Member variable init */
{
  // Create thread and specify sensitivity
  SC_THREAD(do_Fifo_shift);
    sensitive << CLK.pos();
}

// Destructor
Fifo_shift::~Fifo_shift()
{ /* Delete dynamic variables */ }

// Function to perform opperation
void Fifo_shift::do_Fifo_shift()
{ /* Process implementation */ }

/* Additional module implementations */
```

Is there a way to accomplish this format with multiple implementations of modules in a single file using the `SC_HAS_PROCESS` macro? I am new to SystemC, so I am hoping there is a simple solution to this but have not found any through searching the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE 1666-2011 LRM (the standard definition for SystemC) says

> Macro SC_HAS_PROCESS shall only be used within the class definition,
> constructor body, or member function body of a module. The name of the
> module class being constructed shall be passed as the argument to the
> macro. The macro invocation shall be terminated with a semicolon.

It looks like you're using the macro in the global scope.

If you haven't already, you can download a copy of the LRM from [here](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1666-2011.html).

Comment: Thanks for the standard definition. I guess the SC_HAS_PROCESS cannot be used as I wanted. I fixed the problem by moving the statement to the header file definition and will update my post to reflect the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You have the same code in multiple areas.

As can be seen in below/above error meassages:

```
src/Decoder.cpp:146:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘SC_HAS_PROCESS’
 SC_HAS_PROCESS(Fifo_shift);
 ^
src/Decoder.cpp:50:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘SC_HAS_PROCESS’
 SC_HAS_PROCESS(Decoder);
```

Look in lines 146 and 50.

Comment: I have included those portions of the code in my question. The error may be coming from the expansion of the **SC_HAS_PROCESS** macro, however this statement is needed before the constructor in SystemC.

Comment: Then I would declare it inside the class before the constructor, not outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors regarding `SC_HAS_PROCESS()` and was able to address them by putting the usage of the `SC_HAS_PROCESS()` macro within the definition of the constructor, as described here: [link](https://learnsystemc.com/basic/sc_has_process).

```
Fifo_shift::Fifo_shift(sc_module_name nm, int chunk_size_in) :
  /* Member variable init */
{
  SC_HAS_PROCESS(Fifo_shift);
  // Create thread and specify sensitivity
  SC_THREAD(do_Fifo_shift);
    sensitive << CLK.pos();
}
```